# How to Redirect to the main page from pop up window in html

Tags: php, html

I have a html page to login via gmail account . for that am using pop up window for login. Here i menstion the code,

My HTML Code :

```
<body>
<a href="<?php echo $login_url; ?>"target="popup" 
    onclick="window.open('<?php echo $login_url; ?>','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;">
      Sign in with Gmail
 </a>
</body>
```

If  i click the Sign in with Gmail button means  gmail is opened in a pop up. but after giving mail id and password and click sign in means my next page is loaded inside the pop up only.

But i want to close the pop up window after sign in and redirect to my main page . How to do that. please any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `onclick` handler and the `popup` target:

```
<a href="<?= $login_url ?>>
      Sign in with Gmail
</a>
```

Comment: If i  remove that onclick handler means it will be opened in blank window only

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no target="popup" property for href.

Once google send user to your redirect URL, on that page add this to close the opened window.

```
echo "<script> 
    window.close();
    window.opener.location.reload();
</script>"; // close the pop up window and refresh the page
```

Comment: can you post the link of site?